# ASP.net MVC Website Wrapped in a Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, model-view-controller, wrapper

I've a Asp.net MVC website which I want to wrap in a Cordova/PhoneGap app.

Requirements:
I do not want to make any changes to my existing MVC website. I just want to wrap this website and host it in a simple app. The mobile app will act as a wrapper and will just load the external website. I can add some App specific features later.

Things I did:
I installed all the Android and other Mobile ios specific SDKs in Visual Studio 2013 and am able to bring up a non-mvc site (like salesforce.com) in a sample cordova app by making below changes in cordova application.

1) index.js
 window.location = "https://www.salesforce.com/";

2) config.xml
content src="index.html"

access origin="http://salesforce.com/" subdomains="true"

However, I couldn't find any solution to bring up a MVC site.
Can someone help me in this by using any jquery or javascript/ajax to load my external website (for ex: stackoverflow.com)?

Or, is there any other way apart from Cordova??

Comment: Cordova relies on javascript, html and css with the occasional native plugin. You're not going to get asp.net on there.

Comment: I'm able to pull up a home page using jquery cross origin plugin. js/jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js . But when you click on any of the links it opens up in a browser instead of within the app.